# negative top value makes parent div higher

Tags: css

I try to position a div relative to its parent with a negative top value. This works fine, the problem is now that this div, even it has a negative top value makes the parent div bigger.

What could I do to make the parent div not bigger?

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9925e7dz/).

I do not want that the `.innera-rel` `div` makes the `.a` `div` bigger (I dont want to see the red at the bottom).

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="innera">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
  <div class="innera-rel">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
  background: red;
}
.innera {
  height: 80px;
  background: blue;
}

.innera-rel {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    right: -50px;
    top: -38px;
    width: 130px;
}
```

Comment: The negative margin does not make the div higher. https://jsfiddle.net/9925e7dz/1/ I get what you are after but I think you need to rephrase the question.

Comment: You might want to set position of `.a` as relative and position of `.inera-rel` as absolute. Then you will position `.inera-rel` relatively to the upper left corner of `.a`.

Comment: you are on the wrong path, start from this: https://jsfiddle.net/9925e7dz/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red space you see is the space that the .innera-rel would take up if it was not positioned. This space stays "occupied", you just move the div around relative to that space. If you do not want this to happen you have to use absolute positioning.

Comment: yes exacty, my problem with absolute positioning is, that I want it relative to the element above it. In this example I want the `.innera-rel` relative to `.innera`. The only way I can think about that is to have a container containing this 2 elements and then position the `.innera-rel` absolute to this container. Or is there a way without this container?

Comment: You could get rid of the first container and add a `float: left` to the second like so: https://jsfiddle.net/9925e7dz/6/ or so: https://jsfiddle.net/9925e7dz/7/ but i am not sure what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the same height to the .a

```css
.a {
  background: red;
    height: 80px;
}
.innera {
  height: 80px;
  background: blue;
}

.innera-rel {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    right: -50px;
    top: -38px;
    width: 130px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="innera">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
  <div class="innera-rel">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.a {
  background: red;
  height:80px;
}
.innera {
  height: 80px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Make the `.a` height same as the `.innera` height

Answer (score -1):

This will make the red bar disappear:

```
.a {
  display: inline;
}
```